# How to get notified when different events happened with RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-location, android-maps-v2

I have an app which uses Google maps and location updates. I also call two APIs with vital information for my app.
I need some way to get notified when all these cases are completed:

1. Google Map is loaded.
2. I got my current location.
3. I have made both calls to APIs.

I tried RxJava with Retrofit for the asynchronous calls and I get notified with one Observable, but I don't know how to determinate when the map is loaded and when I get my current location.

Is there a way to achieve that using Rxjava? Or is there another way to get notified when all these events have finished?

Comment: I think onMapReady & onLocationResult may solve your problem

Comment: Create observable out of those events and use zip operator

Comment: Hi @than, how can I create an observable out of these two events: Maps is loaded and got my current location? I know once I get subscribed I will start all the observables, but these two events get called once they have finished so my observable will be waiting for them until they notify something, right?

Answer (score 1):

For Google Map loaded you can use `MapReady` from [RxGoogleMaps](https://github.com/sdoward/RxGoogleMaps). Note: the library is not actively maintained so maybe you should check the implementation and reuse the part you need.

For the location you can use [RxLocation](https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation)

For the API calls you can use the `Observable` support from Retrofit.

For combining the result you can use the [zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).